# How to pip install using Vstudio?

Tags: python, visual-studio

That's about it. How do i pip install things like tqdm using Vstudio, as i can't find a shell (I think that's what it's called.)
Do i just add it using pythonn 3.11 shell?
(I am a script kiddie, so i don't have the most knowledge on this.)
I tried installing it using a regular .py program, but it obviously didn't work.
All of the Youtube tutorials and whtanot don't look the same as mine, or just don't work.
if this is a bad question, or I am just asking the wrong place, i would love to know as it is my first post here.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean Visual Studio (purple logo) or Visual Studio Code (blue logo)?

Comment: Visual Studio with purple logo.